# Что такое buffer_size?

Tags: php

Когда я вызываю `ob_get_status()`, я получаю массив, в котором помимо прочего присутствуют строка `buffer_size` и `chunk_size`.

Что такое `chunk_size` я, кажется понял. Это значение `output_buffering` из `php.ini` либо которое задаётся через `ob_start()`.

А вот что такое `buffer_size` я не понимаю? Я заметил, что его значение меняется в зависимости от заданного значения `chunk_size`.

Что это такое? Почему это зависит от `chunk_size`? Где в документации это отражено?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации, [как видно](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-status.php) - никак не отражено. Ну и ладно, пошли так почитаем. Как известно, `PHP` является проектом с открытым исходным кодом и написан на `C`.

- код реализации PHP функции `ob_get_status` начинается в [`main/output.c` на 1495 строке](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.2.2/main/output.c#L1495) (на примере `PHP 7.2.2`)
- если был запрошен `full_status`, то массив результата заполняется немного выше в методе `php_output_stack_apply_status`, который вызывает в свою очередь [`php_output_handler_status`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.2.2/main/output.c#L1174)
- там вполне видны все элементы результирующего массива. Интересующие `buffer_size` и `buffer_used` - это свойства структуры [`php_output_buffer`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.2.2/main/php_output.h#L93)

Как используются эти свойства можно почитать в этих же двух файлах, но суть сведётся к одному выводу:

Память операционной системой выделяется блоками, относительно быстродействия непосредственно кода выделение блока памяти более дорогостоящая операция. И что более неприятно для буфера вывода, если блока памяти не хватило и надо ещё несколько байт - возможно новый блок окажется в другом месте и потребуется копировать все данные в новое место. Поэтому в `C` для мест, где вероятно понадобится увеличение объёма данных нередко запрашивают буфер больше чем требуется в самом начале.

В итоге, `buffer_size` - это именно зарезервированный объём памяти в байтах, который сейчас выделен для хранения данных. `buffer_used` - сколько байт этого буфера занято. Показываются просто детали низкоуровневой реализации.

С `chunk_size` непосредственно не связан, но при достижении размера `chunk_size` данные отправляются на вывод, поэтому если `chunk_size` был задан - то мы заранее знаем максимальный объём необходимой памяти и можем [выделить буфер ровно этого размера](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.2.2/main/output.c#L863). Дальше ещё чуток логики - блок округляется до 4кб (для целей выравнивания блока по размеру страниц памяти операционной системы, судя по именам констант), если же `chunk_size` указан не был - то выделяется для начала 16кб.